# LINQ to JSon response

Tags: c#, json, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have posted my class below and with sample data. I need to pass this class as an json response.

```
[Serializable]
public class Student
{
    public string Fname {get;set;}
    public string FirstSemMarkcsv {get;set;}  //This should hold marks as comma separated values.
    public string SecondSemMarkcsv {get;set;}  //This should hold marks as comma separated values.
}
```

Sample Data

```
Fname     FirstSemMark       SecondSemMark
John               95                  90
John               80                  93
John               70                  80
Peter              60                  78
Peter              80                  80
Peter              90                  85
```

I need to pass this as json response.

Any thoughts please.

Regards,

Ashish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Student> students = GetStudentList();
return Json(students));
```

Comment: Can you please provide description for GetStudentList() method?

Comment: Well, how are you accessing the database? How do you populate any entity in your project?

Comment: I have that in SharePoint custom list. You can assume datatable.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think my answer well help as Json is a method of the MVC.Controller class. I assumed you had an MVC project.

Comment: Thanks for steve looking into this.